# How to fix ttk.Entry() object showing up as None?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Whenever I try to do `ttk.Entry.delete(0, END)` on the `Entry()` object, it gives me an AttributeError. The Entry widget is showing up as None. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proper example on how it should be:

```
a = ttk.Entry(root)
a.pack()
```

This is because in python when saying `x = a().b()`, `x` will have the value returned by `b()`, so in this case `pack()` returns `None`, hence you are having `x` as `None` and when you say `x.delete(0,END)` you are literally saying `None.delete(0,END)` which gives you the error your getting.

Also as a sidenote, saying `ttk.Entry.delete(0,END)` will give you different error as it should be `ttk.Entry().delete(0,END)`, which wont produce any error.

So always keep in mind to declare in one line and put in on the screen in another line.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about this in tkinter. Lol

Comment: @DeeDeeAich Would appreciate marking as answer.

Comment: Sorry. Couldn’t do it yesterday and forgot lol.